# ActiveAdmin - has_many and arbitrary html with the newer (1.0.0) dsl

Tags: activeadmin

Due to dependency complications from today's Rails and Sprockets vulnerability updates, I had to update ActiveAdmin to HEAD today, and the upgrade has done a number on one of my more complicated forms. See here for a much-simplified example: http://pastebin.com/Gt19TtYW

This markup rendered fine in the last version we were using (ref 8299dee5bd0) - the arbitrary html in the innermost `inputs` blocks rendered and each `item.input` as expected. However, in the newest version, only the last method invoked in the block is respected (so only `<p>More static html</p>` renders for each item). Even if I remove those static html containers and leave only `item.input` calls, I only get markup for the last method call in the block. This leaves me with two questions:

- Is there a new preferred way to include arbitrary html under the new DSL? I tried `div` as per https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/5-forms.md but that just made things worse (the arbitrary html ended up floating orphaned above the has_many markup).
- Is there some new trick for the syntax inside `has_many` to get all of my `item.input` and other markup to render, instead of just the last thing called?

Answer (score 2):

yes please do open issue(s) on GitHub for this.  Our intention was that you use Arbre inside the inputs, so "para some static html" rather than "<p> ... <p>".html_safe  However, so far this works inside inputs but not has_many.  Also a fix was just added to has_many for the missing input so pull the latest and see if that helps.

Comment: Did so at https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3570, thank you for confirming that this is a bug and not just a syntax change.